# Fill missing values rowwise (right / left)

Tags: r, dplyr, na

I'm looking for a way to "fill" `NA`s to the right (as opposed to down/up) with dplyr.  In other words, I would like to convert d into d2 without having to explicitly reference any columns in a mutate call.

My real dataframe has several 10s of fields with staggered blocks of NAs spanning variable numbers of columns.  I'm curious whether there's a short way to globally inherit the first non-NA value to the left, regardless of what field it occurs in.

```
d<-data.frame(c1=c("a",1:4), c2=c(NA,2,NA,4,5), c3=c(NA,3,4,NA,6))
d2<-data.frame(c1=c("a",1:4), c2=c("a",2,2,4,5), c3=c("a",3,4,4,6))
d
d2
```

Comment: Wouldn't this cause an imbalance in `type` as the first column is `factor`,  If 'a' replace the NA is first row, then the other column types also change.

Comment: That would certainly be a problem for many use cases but, for this one, I'm treating everything as text prior to a dplyr chain that will gather/spread/mutate the data to a nice "long" format with a mix of numeric & character columns.  I'm working with data from a pdf exported from an excel file that used merged cells for multiple column headers.  The number of columns that form a block of data related to one location varies but the column with a value always seems to be the left-most one from the block luckily.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

We can do a `gather` into 'long' format, do the `fill` grouped by the row number and then `spread` back to 'wide' format

```
library(tidyverse)
rownames_to_column(d, 'rn') %>% 
    gather(key, val, -rn) %>%
    group_by(rn) %>% 
    fill(val) %>% 
    spread(key, val) %>%
    ungroup %>%
    select(-rn)
# A tibble: 5 x 3
#  c1    c2    c3   
#  <chr> <chr> <chr>
#1 a     a     a    
#2 1     2     3    
#3 2     2     4    
#4 3     4     4    
#5 4     5     6
```

---

or another option without reshaping would be doing rowwise fill with `na.locf`

```
library(zoo)
d %>% 
    mutate(c1 = as.character(c1)) %>%
    pmap_dfr(., ~ na.locf(c(...)) %>%
                      as.list %>%
                      as_tibble)
```

---

Also, if we use `na.locf`, it run columnwise, so the data can be transposed and apply `na.locf` directly

```
d[] <- t(na.locf(t(d)))
d
#  c1 c2 c3
#1  a  a  a
#2  1  2  3
#3  2  2  4
#4  3  4  4
#5  4  5  6
```

As @G.Grothendieck mentioned in the comments, inorder to take care of the elements that are NA at the beginning of the row, use `na.locf0` instead of `na.locf`

Comment: super.  I will try both approaches.  I like the simplicity of the zoo::na.loc and I should have thought of the gather/spread on row number myself.  The whole reason I need to do the filling operation is to make future gather/spread operations work properly.

Comment: Might want to use.`na.locf0` here in case first elements in a row are NA.

Comment: This worked beautifully for my task at hand.  My source data were structured in a table that was wrapped to the page (i.e. table header repeated 4 to 5 times per page) and there were ~20 pages.  I also realized that there were a few NAs in my data that I wanted preserve.  My strategy was simply to add row_number as a field, create one df by filtering on field headers that I wanted to use na.locf on and create a 2nd df containing the actual data.  I then bound the tables by row, sorted on the original row header and then moved on with my tidyr chain to convert to "long" format.

Comment: @DanStrobridge  Glad to know it is working for you.  Regarding the other comments, I am not following it.  Are you saying that there is some issue

Comment: @DanStrobridge  You can subset those data by the ids you are using and then do the`na.locf` on the other dataset

Comment: No issues.  Everything is working now.  I'm glad to have learned about na.locf.  Thanks so much.

Comment: This calculations works for me but has one glitch: My first column contains names and all the data is shifted over one column to the left. So now the `name` column has data from `column 2`; `column 2` has data from `column 3`; and my last column of data is now named `name`. There are no `NA`s in the `name` column by the way.

Comment: edit: I used d[] <- t(na.locf(t(d)))

Comment: @seansteele perhaps you meant to do `d[-1] <- t(na.locf(t(d[-1])))`

Answer (score 6):

We can apply `zoo::na.locf` row-wise using `apply`

```
d[] <- t(apply(d, 1, zoo::na.locf))

d
#  c1 c2 c3
#1  a  a  a
#2  1  2  3
#3  2  2  4
#4  3  4  4
#5  4  5  6
```

Comment: See na.locf0 comment on other answer.