# Replace missing value of all the following columns based on the value of preceding column

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have a dataframe like below:

```
  SampleId  Col1  Col2  Col3  Col4
1  st1       k     p     
2  st2       k
3  st3       k     p     g
4  st4       k     p     g      s
```

I want the empty rows in the columns to be filled based on the available values from preceding columns, so something like below:

```
  SampleId  Col1  Col2  Col3  Col4
1  st1       k     p     p     p
2  st2       k     k     k     k
3  st3       k     p     g     g
4  st4       k     p     g     s
```

What would be a `dplyr` way to do this?

Comment: The empty cells are `""` or `NA`?

Comment: Hello! welcome to SO! the following link might help a bit: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Most importantly for your question: You have a current dataframe and an expected output, can you share in your question the code you already tried to use?

Comment: The empty cells are " "

Comment: Could you specify what the empty cells are to your post? It's necessary infromation for this question.

Comment: Very similar question to [Fill missing values rowwise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55671205/fill-missing-values-rowwise-right-left)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could transform the data to long, replace `""` with `NA`, and fill in missing values with the previous value with `fill()`. Finally, transform the data back to wide.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  pivot_longer(starts_with('Col')) %>%
  mutate(value = na_if(value, "")) %>%
  fill(value) %>%
  pivot_wider()

# # A tibble: 4 × 5
#   SampleId Col1  Col2  Col3  Col4
#   <chr>    <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
# 1 st1      k     p     p     p
# 2 st2      k     k     k     k
# 3 st3      k     p     g     g
# 4 st4      k     p     g     s
```

---

###### Data

```r
df <- structure(list(SampleId = c("st1", "st2", "st3", "st4"),
Col1 = c("k", "k", "k", "k"), Col2 = c("p", "", "p", "p"), Col3 = c("", "", "g", "g"),
Col4 = c("", "", "", "s")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4"))
```

Comment: Thank you so much Darren, I will try this with my Data.

Comment: I had  a similar question about modifying taxonomic string in which is not possible to do pivot longer, I just posted this question again. If you can kindly look at it.